# Missing operator -3 not recognized as internal or external command. - batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

i have this piece of code, which runs and completes as expected. but gives the errors following errors.

```
Missing operator.
'-3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Missing operator.
'-3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
r.6.5.mca
```

It does echo the correct answer though which is the r.6.5.mca

Here is the code

```
SET /a minrand=-3
SET /a maxrand=3
set /a placeobject=0
set /a createname=0
set /a oldX=5
set /a oldY=2

SET /a shiftX=%RANDOM% %% (maxrand-minrand+1)+minrand rem will set shiftX to number between %maxrand% & %minrand%
SET /a shiftY=%RANDOM% %% (maxrand-minrand+1)+minrand rem will set shiftY to number between %maxrand% & %minrand%
SET /a newX= (oldX+shiftX)
SET /a newY= (oldY+shiftY)

echo r.%newX%.%newY%.mca
pause
```

one thing i have noticed is the problem does not happen if minrand is a positive number. for this program though it has to be a negative number. keep in mind it works but throws errors.

Comment: I don't know if it will work but have you tried wrapping the `-3` in quotes? `SET /a minrand="-3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `rem` within the line like that. Move them to a separate line and all your troubles are gone.